# Smooch Pre-Create App User API requires scope app and userId, but also doesnt allow userId with scope app

Tags: smooch

There appears to be a conflict between the validation of the request and the requirements of the request. The API call requires that the scope be set to 'app'. It also requires a userId. However, when the two are combined you get the below messages indicating you cannot combine the two.

API https://docs.smooch.io/rest/#pre-create-app-user

REQUEST

```
{ host: 'api.smooch.io',
  path: '/v1/appusers',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
}
```

Example body.

```
{
  scope: 'app',
  userId: 'some_userId',
  credentialRequired: true,
  email: 'test@email.com',
  properties: { picture: 'https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/.....' }
}
```

RESPONSE BODY

```
{"error":{"code":"bad_request","description":"Invalid JWT body. Cannot use userId param with app scope"}}
```

RESPONSE HEADERS

```
  { connection: 'close',
     server: 'nginx',
     date: 'Tue, 21 Feb 2017 14:47:50 GMT',
     'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     'content-length': '105',
     'x-powered-by': 'Express',
     vary: 'X-HTTP-Method-Override',
     etag: 'W/"69-huba/v8EazhrDAoySthrKw"',
     via: '1.1 vegur' },
  statusCode: 400,
  statusMessage: 'Bad Request' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be confusing two separate concepts - the JWT payload vs the HTTP request body.

`scope` is defined in the payload of your JWT credential (`Bearer ${token}` in your code sample). More information about JWTs and scopes can be found [here](https://docs.smooch.io/rest/?shell#jwt).

`userId` should be specified in the HTTP request body.

I'm not sure what language you're using, but here's an example in Node.js:

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var token = jwt.sign({ scope: 'app' }, SECRET, { headers : { kid: KEY_ID } });

var request = require('request');
request.post({
    url: 'https://api.smooch.io/v1/appusers',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    },
    json: {
        userId: 'some_userId',
        credentialRequired: true,
        email: 'test@email.com',
        properties: { picture: 'https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/.....' }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the obvious mixing up of the two payloads. Applying this fixed helped me figure out that I was also not properly submitting the payload to the request as well. Looks like this was entirely a PEBCAK problem.